# How to generate a session id with kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, opentok, tokbox

I am just trying to create a new session on openTok:

```
val openTok = OpenTok(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
        val session: com.opentok.Session? = openTok.createSession(
            SessionProperties.Builder()
                .mediaMode(MediaMode.RELAYED)
                .build()
        )
```

However, Every time I try to run this code, it returns the same error:

```
  Caused by: com.opentok.exception.RequestException: Could not create an OpenTok Session
    at com.opentok.util.HttpClient.createSession(HttpClient.java:88)
    at com.opentok.OpenTok.createSession(OpenTok.java:247)
```

Comment: Is the INTERNET permission declared in the Manifest?

Comment: yeah i have:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Check and confirm your API_KEY and API_SECRET

Comment: the key and secret are correct

Comment: what's the full stacktrace? And what's happening at line 88 of that ``HttpClient`` file

Comment: hi @duncboi69 you resolved this question?